# Powershell script AD search non-indexed field

Tags: powershell

I have a need to query AD based on a field that is not one of the fields that is not indexed. We have a field called `EmployeeID`. When I try to filter on that I get a invalid argument. I can query for any indexed field but I just don't have those.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$users = ForEach ($user in $(Get-Content "C:\Users\leaker.AUTH\Documents\MADO - General\Tools\ED Dump tool\ED Dump tool\badgem.txt"))
{

    Get-AdUser $user -filter "EmployeeID -eq '$_.employeeID)'" -Properties SamAccountNAme,displayName,employeeID,mail

}

 $users |
 Select-Object SamAccountNAme,displayName,employeeID,mail |
 Export-CSV -Path "C:\Users\leaker.AUTH\Documents\MADO - General\Tools\ED Dump tool\ED Dump tool\output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for the code issue

Comment: The `Filter` string will literally expand to: `"EmployeeID -eq '.employeeID)'"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$user` will be bound to the `Identity` parameter - `Filter` and `Identity` does not exist in the same parameter set.

Remove `-filter "EmployeeID -eq '$_.employeeID)'"`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your CSV has a field named "employeeID"? If so, that will be a property of the `$name` variable that is created in the ForEach loop.

You don't need the $user argument for `Get-ADUser` and it looks like your filter syntax has strange brackets and quotes in it. Try the following:

```
...
Get-ADUser -Filter {EmployeeID -eq $name.employeeId} -Properties samAccountNAme,displayName,employeeID,mail
...
```